# OBJECT_CONSTRUCT function is not working properly

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

[image]

[image]

output--

[image]

I have written the query in snowflake to generate Json file, from the query output want to remove fields which has NULL.  OBJECT_CONSTRUCT is not working properly for some column its not passing NULL value where else for some column its giving null value as result.

Input-
Json remove any field which has value NULL or blank.
`{"DIFID":122,"DIF_FLAG":"NULL","DIF_TYPE":"asian/white","FOCAL_COUNT":2370,"REFERENCE_COUNT":17304},`

Required Output-
Json remove any field which has value NULL or blank.
`{"DIFID":122,"DIF_TYPE":"asian/white","FOCAL_COUNT":2370,"REFERENCE_COUNT":17304},`

query-

```
select distinct ITEMSTATID,object_construct( 
                             'DIFID',DIFID,
                              'DIF_TYPE',DIF_TYPE,
                              'DIF_FLAG',DIF_FLAG,
                              'FOCAL_COUNT',FOCAL_COUNT::integer,
                              'REFERENCE_COUNT',REFERENCE_COUNT::integer,
                              'DIF_METHOD',DIF_METHOD,
                              'DIF_VALUE',DIF_VALUE)
DIF
from DEV_IPM.STAGEVAULT.DIF_STATISTICS;
```

Comment: can you share your query?

Comment: select distinct ITEMSTATID,array_agg(object_construct( 

                                 'DIFID',DIFID,
                                  'DIF_TYPE',DIF_TYPE,
                                  'DIF_FLAG',DIF_FLAG,
                                  'FOCAL_COUNT',FOCAL_COUNT::integer,
                                  'REFERENCE_COUNT',REFERENCE_COUNT::integer,
                                  'DIF_METHOD',DIF_METHOD,
                                  'DIF_VALUE',DIF_VALUE)
 )DIF
  
from DEV_IPM.STAGEVAULT.DIF_STATISTICS group by ITEMSTATID ;

Answer (score 2):

For string column and 'NULL' as **string literal** column's value is not skipped:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE DIF_STATISTICS 
AS
SELECT 1 AS ITEMSTATID,
       122 AS DIFID,
       'NULL' AS DIF_FLAG,   -- here
       'asian/white' AS DIF_TYPE,
       2370 AS FOCAL_COUNT,
       17304 AS REFERENCE_COUNT;
```

Output:

[image]

The value is definitely stored as TEXT:

```
SELECT null AS DIF_FLAG, 'NULL' AS DIF_FLAG;
```

On the left: true NULL on the right: NULL string

[image]

If it the case then it should be nullified `NULLIF(DIF_FLAG, 'NULL')` before passing to `OBJECT_CONSTRUCT` function:

```
SELECT ITEMSTATID,
  object_construct(
    'DIFID',DIFID,
    'DIF_TYPE',DIF_TYPE,
    'DIF_FLAG',NULLIF(DIF_FLAG, 'NULL'),
    'FOCAL_COUNT',FOCAL_COUNT::integer,
    'REFERENCE_COUNT',REFERENCE_COUNT::integer) AS DIF
FROM DIF_STATISTICS;
```

---

Previous answer before column details were provided (also plausible):

It is working as intended:

> [NULL Values](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/semistructured-considerations.html#null-values)
>
> Snowflake supports two types of NULL values in semi-structured data:
>
> - SQL NULL: SQL NULL means the same thing for semi-structured data types as it means for structured data types: the value is missing or unknown.
> - **JSON null (sometimes called “VARIANT NULL”): In a VARIANT column, JSON null values are stored as a string containing the word “null” to distinguish them from SQL NULL values.**

> [OBJECT_CONSTRUCT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/object_construct.html#usage-notes)
>
> If the key or value is NULL (i.e. SQL NULL), the key-value pair is omitted from the resulting object. A key-value pair consisting of a not-null string as key and a **JSON NULL as value (i.e. PARSE_JSON(‘NULL’)) is not omitted.**

---

For true SQL NULL values, that column is ommitted:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE DIF_STATISTICS 
AS
SELECT 1 AS ITEMSTATID,
       122 AS DIFID,
       NULL AS DIF_FLAG,
       'asian/white' AS DIF_TYPE,
       2370 AS FOCAL_COUNT,
       17304 AS REFERENCE_COUNT;

SELECT ITEMSTATID,
  object_construct(
    'DIFID',DIFID,
    'DIF_TYPE',DIF_TYPE,
    'DIF_FLAG',DIF_FLAG,
    'FOCAL_COUNT',FOCAL_COUNT::integer,
    'REFERENCE_COUNT',REFERENCE_COUNT::integer) AS DIF
FROM DIF_STATISTICS;
```

Output:

[image]

---

Probably the data type of the column  `DIFID` is VARIANT/OBJECT:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE DIF_STATISTICS 
AS
SELECT 1 AS ITEMSTATID,
       122 AS DIFID,
       PARSE_JSON('NULL') AS DIF_FLAG,    -- here
       'asian/white' AS DIF_TYPE,
       2370 AS FOCAL_COUNT,
       17304 AS REFERENCE_COUNT;
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Data type id varchar for all fields . Query is giving correct result for other fields but not giving for DIF_FLAG.

Comment: @Nidhi Are you storing **NULL value** or **'NULL' string**? `SELECT * FROM DEV_IPM.STAGEVAULT.DIF_STATISTICS WHERE DIF_FLAG ILIKE 'NULL'`?

Comment: @Nidhi They are not NULL values but NULL strings!

Comment: yes you are right. Good catch. Thanks let me correct value in field.